# Git bash can not run any ng command (Angular CLI)

Tags: bash, angular-cli, git-bash

I'm working on git bash cmd. When I try run `ng` command e.g. `ng serve` or `ng gc new-component` I see this output:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

In the middle of output I see problem with left and right slash. How can I fix it?

I suppose, it isn't problem with environment paths, because all ng commands are working in Windows cmd or PowerShell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see comments from @steveswork at:
  https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29287

You have to delete C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm and C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache and 
  reinstall global npm modules.

(This typically happens after an upgrade or downgrade of node)

Good Luck.